# Using automapper projections with logic in Entity Framework models

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, automapper

I'm porting a webapp to Asp.Net MVC 5 with EF 6 but i'm a bit lost and I don't really know if what I'm trying to do is good, or even possible.
I'm using code first against an existing legacy database with really limited possibilities of schema changes (many apps already running against this database and DBAs not really opened to changes).
I reveresed engineered my POCOs to do some quick tests.

Here is the problem. The app itself is a movies catalog. Database is very normalized with lots of tables and joins, lots of many to many associations with additional info on the relations...
Typical tables and entities example :

```
movie <=> albumsmovies <=> album
movie <=> moviescontents <=> contents
movie <=> movieimages
...
```

And to construct a full "movie" from a customer point of view, I have to go fetch infos everywhere because, for example, the movie genre is its album with highest rank, the movie version is the version of the content with highest rank, ect..

Ideally I want to have pocos with computed properties so I added properties to my movie object like

```
public String Version { get { return moviescontents.Select(mc => mc.Content).OrderBy(score).First().version; } }
```

You see the point. And it works for a single movie, with the magic of EF lazy loading I can get a movie and have my properties calculated automatically. It takes 10 or so queries, but these queries are fast (simple index lookups) so it does the job.

Things are going worse for real catalog pages, where I have like 50 movies to show. I first tried to use include and include everything in my request but it just doesn't work. The SQL generated by EF is often wrong with error of 'identifier' specified multiple times, and when it works it's very slow since it produces huge joins.

I then discovered the automapper projection capabilities and it solved this part of the problem really well. I wrote a createmap like this :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<movie, movieviewmodel>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Id, conf => conf.MapFrom(ol => ol.movieid))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.PictureURL, conf => conf.MapFrom(m => m.moviespictures.FirstOrDefault(mp => mp.typeid == 123).filename))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Genre, conf => conf.MapFrom(m => m.albumsmovies.Where(am => am.album.typeid == 2).Select(am => am.companiesalbum).FirstOrDefault().name))
            .ForMember(
                dto => dto.Version,
                conf => conf.MapFrom(ol => ol.moviescontents.OrderBy(c => c.score).FirstOrDefault().version));
```

This produces very fast and efficient queries.

But my business logic is now in automapper mappings, not in my entities. If I want to keep the possibility to get a single movie poco and keep my properties, i have to duplicate the logic twice : once in the poco properties, once in the automapper mappings. When I try to project from a poco with properties related to other entities, it fails with a "The specified type member '' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."

So, what's the good way to manage this ? I feel i'm missing something here.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a decent solution to this? I'm stuck on the same issue myself.